# PayPal - IPN Not working

Tags: paypal, payment

I can't get my IPN to work,
I've added it, and it sends to the form.  But I can't get the listener to work, I have the following as my listener;

```
<?php

// STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
$keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
if (count($keyval) == 2)
$myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
$get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
} else {
$value = urlencode($value);
}
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
// error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
curl_close($ch);
exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// The IPN is verified, process it:
// check whether the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process the notification

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$con=mysqli_connect("********);
$sessid=$_SESSION['id'];
$check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * Members WHERE id='$sessid'");
$check2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
$totalam = $_POST['mc_gross'] + $check2['credit'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET credit='$totalam' WHERE id='$sessid'");


// IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
// To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
}
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
?>

But
```

it's not working,.  It's not receiving details and adding it to my database,
can anyone help?

I posted it on the paypal forum and got told to come here for more tech support.

Answer (score 0):

After the following line:

`// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly`

Try adding the following line:

`$res = trim($res);`

Comment: Still doesn't like it.  I have added the line, but it's still not adding the record to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the curl verification is not working in your case (it happens in some systems). One of the methods to tackle it will be:

(a) remove the step 2 block , and (b) change the following verified statement to check payment status, and (c) remove the else if block (In my opinion there is no point to do anything if the payment status is not successful, just like if the user clicks the cancel button during the payment process, nothing will be done.)

(a) Remove step 2 block by deleting the following:

```
// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
// error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
curl_close($ch);
exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

(b) change the verified condition to check the payment_status instead.

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

to

```
if (trim($_POST['payment_status'])=="Completed") {
```

(c) remove the else if block by `removing` the following:

```
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
```

Of course another method to tackle the problem is to check and fix your CURL data transfer problem.